# android eclipse setup http POST and GET against web server

Tags: android, eclipse, apache, http

I need help to setup an application in android using eclipse.

I have not used eclipse for JAVA development before so I am a little green as to how this all comes together with android in the mix.

I have a script that I downloaded to test with my web server that has been setup to produce output when accessed (JSON named value pairs at this time).

I am using -
Eclipse IDE for Java Developers
Version: Helios Service Release 2
Build id: 20110218-0911

Android Development Toolkit
Version: 10.0.1.v201103111512-110841

The JAVA code so far -

```
package new.android.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.net.Socket;

import org.apache.http.ConnectionReuseStrategy;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpHost;
import org.apache.http.HttpRequestInterceptor;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.HttpVersion;
import org.apache.http.entity.ByteArrayEntity;
import org.apache.http.entity.InputStreamEntity;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.DefaultConnectionReuseStrategy;
import org.apache.http.impl.DefaultHttpClientConnection;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpEntityEnclosingRequest;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpProtocolParams;
import org.apache.http.params.SyncBasicHttpParams;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext;
import org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpContext;
import org.apache.http.protocol.ExecutionContext;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpProcessor;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor;
import org.apache.http.protocol.ImmutableHttpProcessor;
import org.apache.http.protocol.RequestConnControl;
import org.apache.http.protocol.RequestContent;
import org.apache.http.protocol.RequestExpectContinue;
import org.apache.http.protocol.RequestTargetHost;
import org.apache.http.protocol.RequestUserAgent;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

/**
 * Elemental example for executing a POST request.
 * <p>
 * Please note the purpose of this application is demonstrate the usage of HttpCore APIs.
 * It is NOT intended to demonstrate the most efficient way of building an HTTP client. 
 *
 *
 *
 */

public class search extends Activity {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        HttpParams params = new SyncBasicHttpParams();
        HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
        HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, "UTF-8");
        HttpProtocolParams.setUserAgent(params, "HttpComponents/1.1");
        HttpProtocolParams.setUseExpectContinue(params, true);

        HttpProcessor httpproc = new ImmutableHttpProcessor(new HttpRequestInterceptor[] {
                // Required protocol interceptors
                new RequestContent(),
                new RequestTargetHost(),
                // Recommended protocol interceptors
                new RequestConnControl(),
                new RequestUserAgent(),
                new RequestExpectContinue()});

        HttpRequestExecutor httpexecutor = new HttpRequestExecutor();

        HttpContext context = new BasicHttpContext(null);

        HttpHost host = new HttpHost("localhost", 80);

        DefaultHttpClientConnection conn = new DefaultHttpClientConnection();
        ConnectionReuseStrategy connStrategy = new DefaultConnectionReuseStrategy();

        context.setAttribute(ExecutionContext.HTTP_CONNECTION, conn);
        context.setAttribute(ExecutionContext.HTTP_TARGET_HOST, host);

        try {

            HttpEntity[] requestBodies = {
                    new StringEntity(
                            "This is the first test request", "UTF-8"),
                    new ByteArrayEntity(
                            "This is the second test request".getBytes("UTF-8")),
                    new InputStreamEntity(
                            new ByteArrayInputStream(
                                    "This is the third test request (will be chunked)"
                                    .getBytes("UTF-8")), -1)
            };

            for (int i = 0; i < requestBodies.length; i++) {
                if (!conn.isOpen()) {
                    Socket socket = new Socket(host.getHostName(), host.getPort());
                    conn.bind(socket, params);
                }
                BasicHttpEntityEnclosingRequest request = new BasicHttpEntityEnclosingRequest("POST", 
                        "/android.php");
                request.setEntity(requestBodies[i]);
                System.out.println(">> Request URI: " + request.getRequestLine().getUri());

                request.setParams(params);
                httpexecutor.preProcess(request, httpproc, context);
                HttpResponse response = httpexecutor.execute(request, conn, context);
                response.setParams(params);
                httpexecutor.postProcess(response, httpproc, context);

                System.out.println("<< Response: " + response.getStatusLine());
                System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));
                System.out.println("==============");
                if (!connStrategy.keepAlive(response, context)) {
                    conn.close();
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Connection kept alive...");
                }
            }
        } finally {
            conn.close();
        }        
    }

}
```

Ok main question is why so many imports?

Also I am getting errors for these imports:

```
The import org.apache.http.params.SyncBasicHttpParams cannot be resolved  
The import org.apache.http.protocol.ImmutableHttpProcessor cannot be resolved
```

I cannot see these classes in the android.jar.

Is there a more simple example of implementing a transaction against a web server to obtain a namevaluepair (JSON) for using in the android java application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those errors are because the classes you are referencing are not a part of the standard Android distribution: see http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/params/package-summary.html and http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/protocol/package-summary.html.

Android repackages a specific version of the Apache HTTP library. If you want to use those classes you'll need to include those jars.

Comment: How do I include those jars?
If I include non standard android jars will I have trouble running on an android device?

Comment: Well, I don't know which specific Apache jars you'll need to include: I'm assuming you are using code you had before, so wherever you got that code from should point you to the right jar files. Just add them to your eclipse project and you should be good to go. It shouldn't be a problem with your device.

Comment: Ok I have it sorted now.  I have included the extra packages as part of the build path and no more of those errors